# How do I pass on a variadic argument list while keeping a single argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, variadic-templates

Suppose I have a base class that might later be "extended" by deriving from it, let's call this class `Base`, and the extension `Derived`. **The template signature of the classes is fixed, and cannot be altered** (ie. we cannot change the template arguments to the classes). The writer of the `Derived` class knows nothing about `Base`, only that it *might* take some arguments to its constructor.

However, the caller of the final derived class knows how many arguments should be passed. How can I write this `Derived` extension? Here is what I have:

```
struct Base
{
    Base(int baseArg) {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    template <typename... Args>
    Derived(Args&&... args, int derivedArg)
    :
        Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
    }
};
```

When I try to [run this](http://ideone.com/jw68h6) with `Derived d(1, 1);` I get the following erorr message:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:19:16: error: no matching function for call to 'Derived::Derived(int, int)'
  Derived d(1, 1);
                ^
prog.cpp:19:16: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:11:2: note: template<class ... Args> Derived::Derived(Args&& ..., int)
  Derived(Args&&... args, int myArg)
  ^
prog.cpp:11:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:19:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
  Derived d(1, 1);
                ^
prog.cpp:8:8: note: constexpr Derived::Derived(const Derived&)
 struct Derived : public Base
        ^
prog.cpp:8:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
prog.cpp:8:8: note: constexpr Derived::Derived(Derived&&)
prog.cpp:8:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

The constructor to `Derived` should take 2 arguments, using the first to construct itself and passing the 2nd to the base class. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: put the single argument first in the function signature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Derived` constructor is a non-deduced context. From [temp.deduct.type], §14.8.2.5/5:

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> — [ .. ]
>
> — A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the *parameter-declaration-list*.

In your case, the parameter pack isn't at the end - there's one more argument after it, so it's a non-deduced context, which makes your program ill-formed. The simple solution is to just invert the ordering:

```
template <typename... Args>
Derived(int derivedArg, Args&&... args) // totally OK
:
    Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
{
}
```

Comment: Great, and I really appreciate the standard reference :)

Answer (score 6):

`nth` gets the nth element of some parameters:

```
template<size_t n, class...Args>
auto nth( Args&&... args )
->typename std::tuple_element<n,std::tuple<Args&&...>>::type
{
  return std::get<n>( std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );
}
```

This uses the above to extract the last, and all-but-last, argument and send them to the appropriate spot:

```
struct Derived : public Base {
  struct tag{};
  template <typename... Args>
  Derived(Args&&... args) : Derived(
    tag{},
    std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)-1>{},
    std::forward<Args>(args)...
  ){}
  template<size_t...Is, class...Args>
  Derived(tag, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Args&&...args ):
    Base(nth<Is>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)...)
  {
    int derivedArg = nth<sizeof...(Args)-1>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

We build a sequence for the first n-1 elements, pass them to base, and store the last element for ourselves.

It is far easier if you put the extra argument first, however.

Comment: The C++14 version of `nth` should probably use `decltype(auto)`, no?

Comment: @t.c. yep: but made C++11 period using tuple element.

Comment: What is `tag` for? (you also need a `...` after the first `std::forward`)

Comment: @0x499602D2 `Derived` has a perfect forwarding ctor.  `tag` is a type that won't be in the pack of arguments so I can forward to a 2nd ctor that behaves differently.  Index sequence is not enough, because `Base` could have a ctor that takes an index sequence as the first argument.

Comment: `std::get<n>( std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );` - genius! I'm using this to intercept forwarded arguments and do something different with `<0>` in the derived class (after forwarding to the base). Sorcery!

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - If possible, can you post the complete C++14 version of `nth` as a separate section in your answer?

Comment: @tscgrad The C++11 one is also C++14.  I mean, I would remove the `->` trailing return clause, replace `auto` with `decltype(auto)`, but only for brevity if this was originally a 14 question.